# Why PayPal BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED return an error?

Tags: paypal

I want to confirm the parameters of BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED using WebhookSimulator.

However, an error is returned.

BILLING.PLAN.ACTIVATED etc. will be returned normally.

[image]

```
{
  "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "message": "Invalid data provided",
  "debug_id": "c22eb560f6fa8",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/#errors",
  "details": [
    {
      "location": "body",
      "issue": "Not a valid Resource Type"
    }
  ],
  "links": []
}
```

Do I have to add some parameters?

Comment: Because PayPal is a one big glitchy hole. You'll be surprised how many known bugs they have. I constantly creating tickets asking to fix bugs in their system and in 80% cases they just close tickets because they feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do would be to create a ticket and let them know about this bug.

Go to their support web site:

https://www.paypal-support.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the webhook of sandbox webhook simulator can't be verify

Doc Paypal :
Note: Because these are mock events, you cannot verify, resend an event notification for, or show webhook details for simulator-generated events. For information about how to integrate webhooks, see Webhooks.